# A number within quotes - Regex

Tags: java, regex

I would like a regular expression that matches this: word,"number",word

Where number is something like: 100,000.00

So far I have this but I'm not sure how to check for quotes around a number.

```
(w+)(,)\\(d+)(,)(d+)(.)(d+)(,)\\(w+)(,)
```

Comment: Add quotes in the regex?

Comment: Is number exactly like `100,000.00 ` or it can be for example: `1` `10.0` `0.12345` `1,000,000.12`?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the quotes with escape characters like this:

> \\w+,\\"\\d+,\\d+\\.\\d+\\",\\w+

I remove the last coma...since not part of the pattern.

Comment: Thanks, i am new to regex and didn't know i had to escape quotes.

Comment: @user1155344 Quote is not [special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#SpecialCharacter) in regex, so you don't have to escape it because of that. But they are special characters in Java, so to be able to use it in String as normal character you need to escape its special meaning with `\"`, not `\\"`. Beside that this answer solves your `word,"100,000.00",word` problem :)

Answer (score 0):

In case your number can have few (or none) semicolons with tree digits after it, or precision part can be optional you can use this regex:

```
String regex=
        "\\w+,\"" +     // word, semicolon, quote mark
        "\\d{1,3}" +    // number in form d, dd, or ddd
        "(,\\d{3})*" +  // optional (* means 0 or more times) part of numbers in format ",ddd"  
        "(\\.\\d{2})?" +// optional (? means 0 or 1 time) part ".dd" 
        "\",\\w+";      // quote mark, semicolon, word
```

This will accept:

```
-precision part is optional
d
d.dd 

-number of semicolons can change, but every semicolon MUST have 3 digits after it
dd,ddd
d,ddd,ddd
d,ddd,ddd.dd
```